# converting a python list to arcmap table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, table, list

I have values stored in a list that need processing in the costDistance tool in ArcMap 10.2 (desktop). For this they need to be converted into a table or file readable by arcmap's tools. Anyone with experience doing this?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your list/values?

Comment: i have a string of values (about 4000 rows, four or five columns each) taken from other shapefile attributes using the SearchCursor tool. I would like to put this data into a new shapefile.

Comment: Are you going to same geometry type (e.g. from point to point), or different schema (e.g. from point to non geometry table)?

Comment: polygon to polygon!

Comment: each row is the ID of the polygon

Comment: You could use a insert cursor (destination polygon) within your search cursor (source polygon) and move the column attributes.  If the destination polygon already has the geometry included you should use a update cursor instead of the insert cursor.

Comment: thanks for the help, still not doing quite what i want it to. Do you reckon there is a way to import the values within my string into the attribute table of a new shapefile?

Comment: You mention search cursor tool, are you using ModelBuilder to generate this string?  What does your string look like (is it delimited)?  I'm not sure I understand why you are creating a string from many different columns?

Comment: no I am simply using the python window in arcmap 10.2. the strings are created using the following code `villages = []
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(villagesnear,['IN_FID','NEAR_FID']):
 villages.append(row)

miyun_villages_poly_set = []
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(miyun_villages_poly,'*'):
 miyun_villages_poly_set.append(row)`

Comment: Is there a common ID column/values between your source and destination polygon?

Comment: yes, it does (IN_FID and NEAR_FID both represent OBJECT ID in a shapefile)

Comment: OBJECT ID info is generated by the layer and are typically not seen as a common ID between two different layers.

Comment: Rather than a string of Comments with limited formatting options I recommend that you edit your Question to revise it with the outcomes of your learnings related to it so far.

Answer (score 3):

If you have it in a list you can just loop it out to a CSV file, something like this:

```
outfile = open('name_of_csv.csv','w')
outfile.write("HEADER HERE" + "\n")

for v in THELIST:
    outfile.write(str(v) + "\n")

outfile.close()
```

Note - if you have multiple values - then you must seperate them by a comma if you actually want them in seperate columns.

eg. outfile.write("{0},{1},{2}".format(value1, value2, value3))

Comment: thanks, but it's stored in a string

Comment: Then the example should work fine!

Comment: I keep trying it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: GIve me a snippet of what your list looks like

Comment: here are two entries: (4907, (116.81459311425449, 40.80437439723262), u'v107', u'miyun_data/town73', 3.4055336836), (4908, (116.60279561123411, 40.82509104645453), u'v108', u'miyun_data/town73', 0.135442277771).

Comment: And you want to put this into a text file?

Comment: no, into a feature I can then run arcmap tools with. I'm not sure this is the right approach to the problem, though.

Comment: Where did the original features come from - if they came from a Feature Class - why can't you just copy it.  Otherwise you will have to either write geometries (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001v000000) or write to a text file and then convert it to a point feature class.

Comment: they came from two other shapefiles... i'll try writing geometries now